# Spring boot JPA - json with nested object and id

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-jpa

I am trying to do a project with some basic ORM relationships and REST controllers for sending jsons.

One of my POJOs looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_models")
public class ProductModel extends BaseEntityWithName {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "manufacturer_id")
  @JsonManagedReference
  private ProductManufacturer manufacturer;

  --constr + setters + getters--

}
```

When making get requests, the response looks something like this:

```
{ 
  id: 1, 
  name: "Product 1", 
  manufacturer: {
                   id: 1, 
                   name: "Manufacturer 1"
                 }
}
```

Is there any way to get the request look something like this?(Return both the foreign key id and the nested object)

```
{ 
  id: 1, 
  name: "Product 1", 
  manufacturer_id: 1
  manufacturer: {
                   id: 1, 
                   name: "Manufacturer 1"
                 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add an additional getter to `ProductModel` and make them `@Transient`

```
@JsonProperty("manufacturer_id")
@Transient
public Long getManufacturerId() {
  return manufacturer == null ? null : manufacturer.getId();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, man! I've been trying to get this to work for the past 4 hours, and never tought of this as a solution.